# How fast is fs.readdirSync and can I speed it up?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs

I have a function that gets all the files in a directory recursively using fs.readdirSync.
It works well with the small directory I ran it through as a test, but now that I am running this on a directory that is over 100GB large, it is taking a very long time to complete. Any ideas on how I can speed this up or if there's a better way of doing this? I'm eventually going to have to run this over some directories with Terabytes of data.

```
// Recursive function to get files
function getFiles(dir, files = []) {
    // Get an array of all files and directories in the passed directory using fs.readdirSync
    const fileList = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    // Create the full path of the file/directory by concatenating the passed directory and file/directory name
    for (const file of fileList) {
        const name = `${dir}/${file}`;
        // Check if the current file/directory is a directory using fs.statSync
        if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
            // If it is a directory, recursively call the getFiles function with the directory path and the files array
            getFiles(name, files);
        } else {
            // If it is a file, push the full path to the files array
            files.push(name);
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a single directory with gazillions of files in the first place - filesystems tend to be bad at that. Also, with your current implementation doing that may well run out of memory storing all the filenames.

Comment: Also, you might want to just use `fs/promises`'s asynchronous `readdir` instead.

Comment: Also-also: what does `time find -type f that-big-100gb-directory > /dev/null`  say? Is that slow, too?

Comment: If you talk about `is over 100GB large,`  and `directories with Terabytes of data.`  do you then talk about the size of the files or the count of files?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, when I refer to a directory I am just referring to a network drive that I am scanning through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately going `async` is slower. So we need to optimize your code. You can do it with `{withFileTypes:true}` option and it gets 2x faster.

Also I've tried node v20's `{recursive:true}` option but it's slower than even your solution. And it didn't work with `withFileTypes`.

Maybe a better SSD with high read speed would help. Though file entries are read from a file system index I guess, not sure how hardware affects this.

```
import fs from 'fs';

const DIR = '/bytex';

function getFiles(dir, files = []) {
    // Get an array of all files and directories in the passed directory using fs.readdirSync
    const fileList = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    // Create the full path of the file/directory by concatenating the passed directory and file/directory name
    for (const file of fileList) {
        const name = `${dir}/${file}`;
        // Check if the current file/directory is a directory using fs.statSync
        if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
            // If it is a directory, recursively call the getFiles function with the directory path and the files array
            getFiles(name, files);
        } else {
            // If it is a file, push the full path to the files array
            files.push(name);
        }
    }
    return files;
}

function getFiles2(dir, files = []) {
    const fileList = fs.readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true });
    fileList.forEach(file => file.isDirectory() ? getFiles2(`${dir}/${file.name}`, files) : files.push(`${dir}/${file.name}`));
    return files;
}

let start = performance.now();
let files = getFiles(DIR);
console.log(performance.now() - start);
console.log(files.length);

start = performance.now();
files = getFiles2(DIR);
console.log(performance.now() - start);
console.log(files.length);
```

The output:

```
171.66947209835052
64508
68.24071204662323
64508
```

Comment: For reference, I ran your getFiles2 function over a network drive totaling in 292GB and it took 3.1 hours to complete. Much faster than my original solution. On average twice as fast.

Comment: @Omiinahellcat nice to hear. as i predicted. but your bottleneck is the network. if you could execute the code remotely with the drive as a local one it could be seconds not hours